# Connect to Redis on WSL Windows 10 from remote client

Tags: redis

I've a Redis instance running on a Windows 10 Machine and connecting to Redis locally works perfectly.
When i try to reach Redis from a remote client in the network it doesn't seem to work.

The
Windows machine has the ip 172.22.23.112

Ubuntu WSL 172.22.160.1.

The Firewall for Windows is down, the Port 6379 is enabled on Ubuntu, firewall is down there too.

in redis.conf

bind 127.0.0.1 172.22.23.51 172.22.23.55

protected-mode no

i thought when i connect to the windows machine with a redis client and the appropriate port, windows will forward this request to the WSL Redis Server?

Since i get a timeout i guess i'm doing something wrong!

Answer (score 0):

i set bind to 0.0.0.0

and issued the following command in windows

netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=6379 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=6379 connectaddress=172.x.x.x

where connectaddress is the WSL ip address

connection works, now i've to ensure

1. the wsl ip address is static
2. the command is issued everytime the computer starts

other than that it works